# need to embed child fxml inside parent fxml

Tags: javafx-2

I am new to JavaFX and I want to know if there is way to place one fxml file as in child.fxml inside another say parent.fxml.

Why do i need this ?
Idea is, i want create independent screens(small one) and write a parent fxml where we can add these child fxml to create a desired GUI, instead of one fxml where i dump all the controls.

If it's possible, please help with some dummy code or links. I have tried looking around for a while but did not get anything useful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to use "fx:include" tag. Please refer the [fxml reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html)

Comment: I was exactly looking for the same but was not aware how to use it. Thanks for the reference. It helped.