# JavaFX FXML: Code menu bar once and implement in multiple FXML files

Tags: javafx, fxml, menubar

Is it possible in a FXML-file to include another FXML-file that describes for example a menubar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [need to embed child fxml inside parent fxml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804079/need-to-embed-child-fxml-inside-parent-fxml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. For example:

```
FXMLLoader loader = 
new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("YourFXML.fxml"));
            tabPane.getTabs().get(0).setContent((Node) loader.load());
```

With the setContent Method I could set a FXML as the Content of this tab.
In other panes you could do the same. An anchorpane could do:

```
anchorpane.getChildren().add((Node) loader.load());
```

Hope that helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can includ the file on other fxml file
like this  :

```
<fx:include fx:id="menu" source="../menu/menu.fxml" />
```

exp :

```
<VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
         <fx:include fx:id="menu" source="../menu/menu.fxml" />
        <TabPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="954.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">    
        </TabPane>
     </children>
  </VBox>
```